# How to create Customized Tabs/Views in Android?

Tags: android, text, button, tabs, customization

Can anyone please help me creating highly customized UI as shown below.

```
Labels: tab1 | tab2 | tab3
==========v===============
  Customized ListView
  ...
```

I managed to create the Customized ListView. My problem is creating the Customized tabs.

With help of few tutorials and examples on net, I used Customized TextView for creating Customized Tabs. My problems are:

1. how to show an 'down arrow' exactly below the selected tab/View and overwrite a part of double line below the tabs.
2. As you can see from the design, the first one is the Lable text and then the tabs. Because of this the tab Content covers only the area below the tabs and leaves area below Labels empty. Something like this

   ```
   Labels: tab1 | tab2 | tab3
   ==========v===============
        Customized ListView
               ...
   ```

How can I cover the whole width of the screen through XML settings?

I am able to solve my first problem as follows. I created a custom tab in the following way:

```
    LinearLayout(Vertical Oriantation)
    ---- TextView
    ---- RelativeLayout
         ----LinearLayout
             ---- double Line
         ----DownArrow ImageView(with android:layout_centerInParent = "true", this made the arrow over write the double line)
```

And finally through programming made DownArrow ImageView Invisible and Visible according to the tabs selected.

I am still stuck with the my second Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy solution to your problem is you have a `LinearLayout` with three `Buttons` (or `TextViews`) which will hide your tab. Then you should add the required style to these buttons and implement all the required onclick functionality (i.e. set unselected the other two views, etc, etc), but you gain time by not be obliged to style the tabs, which is a pain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried using Customized TextView for tabs with different backgrounds e.g. 1 with double line(for unselected Tab) and 1 with an 'downArrow' in bewtween the double lines(For selected text) but its not working as per expectations. I am sluck with my 2nd problem can you please help. Thank you Nikhil

Comment: Although your solution helped me. I am still stuck.

Comment: For the arrows, you shoul have two drawables for your "tabs". One for selected state with the arrow centered and one for not selected.